# How to get the text of a single option using it's value with BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I need to access the text of a specific option in a drop down menu using BeautifulSoup. So far I have only been able to find ways to get the text of all the options. I need to use the value assigned to the option but the options are not listed in order. Here is some of the html.

```html
<option value="9">Aerospace Studies</option>
<option value="200">African American Studies</option>
<option value="10">African Languages</option>
<option value="11">African Studies</option>
<option value="12">Afrikaans</option>
<option value="13">Afro-American Studies</option>
<option value="14">American Indian Studies</option>
<option value="198">American Sign Language</option>
<option value="15">Ancient Near East</option>
<option value="16">Anesthesiology</option>
<option value="17">Anthropology</option>
<option value="19">Applied Linguistics</option>
<option value="20">Arabic</option>
<option value="21">Archaeology</option>
<option value="22">Architecture and Urban Design</option>
<option value="23">Armenian</option>
<option value="24">Art</option>
<option value="25">Art History</option>
<option value="26">Arts and Architecture</option>
<option value="201">Arts Education</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to get your question, but here is a way to collect all values and text of all options, and sort them by value.

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup("""<option value="9">Aerospace Studies</option>
<option value="200">African American Studies</option>
<option value="10">African Languages</option>
<option value="11">African Studies</option>
<option value="12">Afrikaans</option>
<option value="13">Afro-American Studies</option>
<option value="14">American Indian Studies</option>
<option value="198">American Sign Language</option>
<option value="15">Ancient Near East</option>
<option value="16">Anesthesiology</option>
<option value="17">Anthropology</option>
<option value="19">Applied Linguistics</option>
<option value="20">Arabic</option>
<option value="21">Archaeology</option>
<option value="22">Architecture and Urban Design</option>
<option value="23">Armenian</option>
<option value="24">Art</option>
<option value="25">Art History</option>
<option value="26">Arts and Architecture</option>
<option value="201">Arts Education</option>""")
print(sorted(list(map(lambda x: (int(x['value']), x.text), soup.find_all('option')))))
```

out

```
[(9, u'Aerospace Studies'), (10, u'African Languages'), (11, u'African Studies'), (12, u'Afrikaans'), (13, u'Afro-American Studies'), (14, u'American Indian Studies'), (15, u'Ancient Near East'), (16, u'Anesthesiology'), (17, u'Anthropology'), (19, u'Applied Linguistics'), (20, u'Arabic'), (21, u'Archaeology'), (22, u'Architecture and Urban Design'), (23, u'Armenian'), (24, u'Art'), (25, u'Art History'), (26, u'Arts and Architecture'), (198, u'American Sign Language'), (200, u'African American Studies'), (201, u'Arts Education')]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I found an alternative solution by doing
`soup.find_all(value= + x)[0].getText()` 
assuming x is the option value you are looking for. Thank you for your solution though.